# Use Team Foundation Server in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, tfs

I'm a .NET developer and use VS2008/TFS2008. Recently, another developer has left our company and now I have to maintain his code. He was a Delphi developer (Delphi 7 mostly, but also Delphi 2007) and he didn't use any source control.

Is there a way to put his code in Team Foundation Server? Integration in the Delphi IDE is a big plus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get IDE integration with TFS in Delphi 7, you need can use the MSSCCI provider for TFS in conjuction with SourceConnexion which gives MSSCCI support to Delphi.  You will need to install the following on your machine if you do not have them already:

1. [Microsoft Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en) (The TFS Client)
2. The [Microsoft MSSCCI provider for TFS 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=faeb7636-644e-451a-90d4-7947217da0e7&displaylang=en)
3. [SourceConnexion](http://www.epocalipse.com/scx.htm)

You need to ensure that you have TFS client access licenses for any of the Delphi folks connecting to TFS and get them a license for the SourceConnexion plug-in.

As you already have VS2008 installed on your machine talking to TFS2008 you probably only need to install items 2 and 3.

See [Eyal's blog post](http://www.epocalipse.com/blog/2006/04/09/team-foundation-server-msscci-provider-10/) for more information (a little out of date but stil valid).

Answer (score 2):

We use SourceConnexion (3rd party plugin) with D2007:
http://www.epocalipse.com/scx.htm

(Works nice with SCC api plugin of Plastic SCM, which has better branching support than TFS :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old thread but during my reserach on how to use TFS2012 with Borland Delphi 2006 the posts here helped me a lot, so I wanted to share my experience.

To use TFS2012 or TFS2010 with Borland Delphi 2006 please follow these steps.

1. Download and install [Microsoft Team Explorer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=329).
2. Download and install [TFS MSSCCI provider TFS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6) (make sure you download the 32-bit version even if on a 64-bit machine!).
3. Download and install [SourceConnexIon](http://www.epocalipse.com).
4. Open Borland Delphi 2006, click on the Source Control menu item and follow the configuration wizzard.

You must follow this order or SourceConneXion won't detect TFS.