# Connecting TFS 2010 from Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, team-explorer

We are using Delphi XE at our company to develop some Delphi applications and as well as .Net.
TFS 2010 is our primarly source control mechanism for .Net; but we want to use TFS 2010 for Delphi.

I installed Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 but i couldn't see any menus or windows at Delphi XE editor about Team Explorer.

So how can we connect Delphi XE to TFS 2010?

Comment: There is an open source project for Delphi XE and XE2 and later, that could be extended (by you) to support TFS, if you feel like doing it.  It's called "Version insight community edition".

Comment: Warren P, if it is developed by Delphi i can not help, because i am a .Net programmer and TFS Admin. But i will check it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK TEE 2010 is an Eclipse plug-in, Delphi is not an Eclilpse based IDE, nor it could use MSSCCI/SCC providers without adds-on. If TFS 2010 can work with an MSSCCI/SCC provider (you may have to [install support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6) separately), then you can use a Delphi add-on, see for example [Use Team Foundation Server in Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862272/use-team-foundation-server-in-delphi-7), it is for Delphi 7 but situation didn't change much.

Delphi XE can use a new API to handle VCS directly, but it is not compatible with older versions (making it less appealing for those who sell already existing add-ons), and thus requires someone to add TFS integration, and TFS is not usually the first choice by Delphi shops. Moreover fashion today dictates that DVCS are hot, and most efforts are in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find or produce a TFS 2010 plugin for the Delphi IDE! To the best of my knowledge, Embarcadero has only integrated SVN (Subversion) into the IDE (XE and XE2).

A quick Google search does not look too promising... so a lot of manual effort may be required on your part, or you may have to simply change your choice of source management solution.